# Is it possible to edit ng generate?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I was wondering if I could customize what would ng generate for angular does. For example, if I want to generate a component, I would like the command to automatically edit my routes file and automatically add a new link based on what was written. Or for another example, I want to use a set of services to be included in my newly-generated component.

This solution would solve the problem of me going around, and importing each individual service to any new component that I am going to generate. So is there any way that I could modify the behavior of the ng generate command or even do some additional things on top of what it does?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [schematics](https://angular.io/guide/schematics)